# Using Panda to split Sheets and sort. What am I missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if this is a basic question.

I've been using code from another user that does: (Excel) Uses the column values to split each one into separate sheets. You also have the option to split the column into different files which I dont use.

I would like to know the most ideal way to:

(Split the column into sheets) then sort a particular column on each sheet by largest to smallest.

How can I add it into this code, or should I use a different script?

Please let me know if there is an easier way to do this.

It's an advertising report with different products, I want to split each product , and for each product sort the keywords that are converting the best (Largest to smallest), so I can easily differentiate the best selling keywords and bad selling. Hopefully i can eventually create something that automatically give me me the keyword that meet the criteria.

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter
from shutil import copyfile

file=input('File Path:')
extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
pth=os.path.dirname(file)
newfile=os.path.join(pth,filename+'_2'+extension)
df=pd.read_excel(file)
colpick=input('Select Column: ')
cols=list(set(df[colpick].values))

def sendtofile(cols):
    for i in cols:
        df[df[colpick] == i].to_excel("{}/{}.xlsx".format(pth, i), sheet_name=i, index=False)
    print('\nCompleted')
    print('Thanks for using this program.')
    return

def sendtosheet(cols):
    copyfile(file, newfile)
    for j in cols:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(newfile, engine='openpyxl')
        for myname in cols:
            mydf = df.loc[df[colpick] == myname]
            mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=myname, index=False)
        writer.save()

    print('\nCompleted')
    print('Thanks for using this program.')
    return

print('You data will split based on these values {} and create {} files or sheets based on next selection. If you are ready to proceed please type "Y" and hit enter. Hit "N" to exit.'.format(', '.join(cols),len(cols)))
while True:
    x=input('Ready to Proceed (Y/N): ').lower()
    if x == 'y':
        while True:
            s = input('Split into different Sheets or File (S/F): ').lower()
            if s == 'f':
                sendtofile(cols)
                break
            elif s == 's':
                sendtosheet(cols)
                break
            else: continue
        break
    elif x=='n':
        print('\nThanks for using this program.')
        break

    else: continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own way of figuring it out! Wow I'm happy!

```
file=input('File Path: ')
data = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df = data.parse(0)
df = df.sort_values(by='7 Day Total Sales ', ascending=False)

writer_orig = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer_orig, index=False, sheet_name='report')
writer_orig.save()
```

I put this before the original code, Start with sorting it, then split into sheets!